# Passing inner function of a struct (or class) as a functor

Tags: c++, stl, functor, function-object

How should I pass a function inside an struct as a functor? I assumed this should work fine, but it didn't:

```
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct s {
    int a[10];

    bool cmp(int i, int j) {
        // return something
    }

    void init() {
        sort(a, a + 10, cmp);
    }
};
```

which gets `<unresolved overloaded function type>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do this directly, because `cmp` is a member function, which requires *three* arguments: `i`, `j`, and the invisible, implicit `this` pointer.

To pass `cmp` to `std::sort`, make it a static function, which does not belong to any particular instance of `s` and thus doesn't have a `this` pointer:

```
static bool cmp(int i, int j) {
    // return something
}
```

---

If you need access to `this`, you can wrap `cmp` in a simple function object instead:

```
struct cmp {
    s &self;
    cmp(s &self) : self(self) { }
    bool operator()(int i, int j) {
        // return something, using self in the place of this
    }
};
```

And call it like this:

```
sort(a, a + 10, cmp(*this));
```

Comment: Why are we using static for this? What does this do?

Comment: @typedeftypename a static member function is basically a free function in a namespace that just happens to actually be the class.

Comment: @typedeftypename: `static` makes it disappear this implicit `this` from the requirements. With it, the function needs just two arguments, `i` and `j`, which are all there.

Answer (score 2):

While @Thomas answer is completely working, You may even do it simpler using `std::bind` or lambdas as follow:

```
// Using std::bind
std::sort( a, a + 10, std::bind(&s::cmp, this, _1, _2) );

// Using lambdas
std::sort( a, a + 1, [this](int i, int j) {return this->cmp( i, j );} );
```

Comment: Wow, great! I suppose this should be the c++0x magic. Too bad I can't use it in my situation.

Comment: You may use `boost::bind` in place of `std::bind`, actually I'm currently using it for this purpose!